# Offset border effect in pure css

Tags: css, border

I am trying to create an offset border effect. Can this be done with pure css.

These are buttons so will be different sizes and colours.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I use pseudo-element :after to create offset border effect.

```css
body {
  background: black;
  padding: 30px;
}
div {
  background: white;
  height: 75px;
  width: 175px;
  position: relative;
}
div:after {
  content: '';
  background: transparent;
  border: 1px solid white;
  top: 7px;
  right: 7px;
  bottom: -7px;
  left: -7px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Update

As [web-tiki pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40528518/offset-border-effect-in-pure-css/40528685?noredirect=1#comment68298708_40528685) in comments on this answer, you can achieve the entire affect entirely with `box-shadow`. Take a look at their JSFiddle demo here: https://jsfiddle.net/5a0bvyup.

I'm going to leave my answer in the state I submitted it in because it does give some idea of how their implementation works (and if you look closely you'll see how their `box-shadow` differs from the one described below).

---

*Note: In my answer I've made the foreground box red instead of white to demonstrate that this 'offset border' does not overlap the initial element. You'll need to change this back to white yourself.*

### The Left and Bottom Borders

You can achieve the left and bottom borders really easily with `box-shadow`. You simply need to create a solid shadow which matches the background colour, and then behind that add a second shadow which matches the foreground colour, offset by one pixel:

```css
body {
  background: black;
  padding: 30px;
}

div {
  background: red;
  height: 72px;
  width: 192px;
  
  box-shadow: -2px 2px 0 5px black, -7px 7px 0 1px white;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

### The Top and Right Borders

You can then use pseudo-elements (`::before` and `::after`) to fill in those extra borders:

```css
body {
  background: black;
  padding: 30px;
}

div {
  background: red;
  height: 72px;
  width: 192px;
  
  box-shadow: -2px 2px 0 5px black, -7px 7px 0 1px white;
  position: relative;
}

div::before {
  background: white;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 1px;
  width: 7px;
  top: 6px;
  right: 100%;
}

div::after {
  background: white;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 7px;
  width: 1px;
  top: 100%;
  right: 6px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: you can make all the borders with 2 box-shadows, like this https://jsfiddle.net/5a0bvyup/

Comment: @web-tiki neat! I knew it was possible but I couldn't remember how. Feel free to add that as an answer yourself as that's more elegant than my approach.

Comment: I won't add another answer but feel free to use the fiddle in yours if you want :)