# CSS offset border

Tags: html, css, border

[image: filled rectangle with offset border]

I’m trying to achieve the effect as shown above in css and html. Haven’t found a possibility to offset a css-border or outline the way I need it.

How can I achieve this effect?

Comment: Hint: *Positioned pseuudo-element* or - Possible Duplicate 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40528518/offset-border-effect-in-pure-css

Comment: You’re right, but I’ve done some research - also on stackoverflow - before i asked. This post explains everything I needed to know: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40528518/offset-border-effect-in-pure-css

Answer (score 2):

```
.square {
  height: 100px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: black;
}

.square::after {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate3d(5px, 5px, 0);
  height: 100px;
  width: 50px;
  border: 3px solid yellow;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Add a pseudo element and offset it.